# Could Someone Explain the BASE64 CSS used by font squirrel

Tags: css, webfonts

I've been using font squirrel to generate web fonts for a while. Usually the CSS it gives is like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'sancoale_slsf_norm_regunormRg';
   src: url(sancoaleslabsoft_normregular_macroman/SancoaleSlSfNormRegular-webfont.eot');
    src: url(sancoaleslabsoft_normregular_macroman/SancoaleSlSfNormRegular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url(sancoaleslabsoft_normregular_macroman/SancoaleSlSfNormRegular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url(sancoaleslabsoft_normregular_macroman/SancoaleSlSfNormRegular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

But playing around with generating the WOFFs as base64 the outputted CSS changes to:

```
 @font-face {
font-family: 'sancoale_slsf_norm_boldnormBd';
src: url('sancoaleslsfnormbold-webfont.eot');
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'sancoale_slsf_norm_boldnormBd';
src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09 [BLABLABLA] =) format('woff'),
     url('sancoaleslsfnormbold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

Does anyone know why the @font-face declaration is split? - Just interested really!

Comment: Here's all you need to know and the best way to do font-face http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/ First one is for IE and second code is for FF, opera and safari

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'd actually read that one already. It specifically mentions the first font squirrel code I've added above but I'm still unsure why when changing to base64 woff that the font-family is declared twice and no longer has that "IE-FIX" bit.

Answer (score 7):

**Base64** is a binary-to-text encoding scheme that represents binary data in an ASCII string format.

**Data URI** is just a URI scheme that provides a way to include data in-line.

Basically, you’re converting the font file into a crazy long string of text that you can paste right in your font-face declaration to replace the font file source link.

*The Data URI Scheme is:*

```
data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>
```

*The Base 64 source in a @font-face looks like:*

```
src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,<your base64 font>) format('woff'),
```

Font Squirrel's generator provides the .eot file as IE support for Base64 began with version 9 (I think).

I've found this method of font-face to have higher deliverability over Paul Irish's bulletproof method.

**Fonts.css** 
In practice, I throw all my base64 encoded fonts (plus weight variations) inside a fonts.css file. This also includes my icon font - which I use [IcoMoon's web app](http://icomoon.io/) to build and get the base64.

Yeah, base64 adds some bulk and it sure isn't pretty, but throwing them all into a central fonts.css file reduces your requests, prevents FOUC, and seems to do a great job of getting around stupid aggressive firewalls that block font file types as default.

[I actually wrote a little post on this a while back.](http://sosweetcreative.com/2613/font-face-and-base64-data-uri)

Comment: Thanks - so the eot part is seen by older IE and base64 by more modern versions? Why don't the modern ones also download the eot file? Or is it just that they don't understand what it is and move on?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is a workaround for the differing data URI support among internet explorer versions. IE 6-7 have no support, IE 8 only supports some elements and only up to 32KB, and IE9+ supposedly works without issue. More info on Data URI support can be found over at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Web_browser_support) and [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/datauri). The 'base64 CSS' option at font squirrel uses data URI encoding.